Trying to find a Benny Hill clip where he's a government bureaucrat offered a woman as a bribe
I'm looking for a scene in a particular episode. My question is, which one?
It lasted only about 10 seconds. A Member of Parliament is sitting in his government office when a lobbyist comes in with a girl in a bikini smiling at him. The MP is outraged.
"WHAT?? You think I'm going to vote for that bill because you bring a woman in here? Get out!"
The lobbyist bows and profusely apologizes."I am SO sorry sir! I am terribly sorry! I appear to have misjudged you."
The door closes, then the guy comes back with a muscular man in a bathing suit. The MP smiles, stands up, and excitedly extends his arms.
